# How to make linked word in org-beamer stands out?

Tags: org-mode, org-link, beamer

I am using org-mode with Beamer.
Using the Barkeley theme, I wrote something like this:

```
To [[http:www.google.com][Google]]
```

However, the outputed slide doesn't indicate any hint of the word "Google" being a link:

[image]

How can I make the word "Google" stands so that the viewer knows that it is clickable and will bring the user to a web page?
Maybe there is a variable that dictates org-mode on how to
convert an org-mode link to a Latex one that I can edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a LaTeX/Beamer question than an Org mode question. You need to tell `hyperref` how to display links. The following Org file should work (I don't have the Barkeley theme, so I used Madrid instead, but it should not make much difference):

```
#+STARTUP: beamer
#+TITLE: Example Presentation
#+OPTIONS: H:2 toc:t num:t
#+LATEX_CLASS: beamer
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation]
#+BEAMER_THEME: Madrid
#+LATEX_HEADER: \definecolor{medium-blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \hypersetup{colorlinks, urlcolor={medium-blue}}

* Header

To [[http:www.google.com][Google]]
```

The link appears blue and if your PDF reader recognizes links (e.g. `xpdf` does), you should be able to click on it.